# New kubernetes deployment (kubernetes-cli) get created automatically with 1000 replicas

Tags: linux, azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-container-service

There was new kubernetes deployment created automatically with 1000 replicas. The same issue occurred a few months ago and then I deleted that kubernetes-cli deployment and pods. After a few months, again I faced this issue, how to prevent this, can anyone help on this.

Created Deployment =>
[image]

Here I monitored kubernetes events with "kubectl get events" command. Relevant events as bellow.
[image]

CPU usage as bellow;
[image]

PID information as bellow;
[image]

Created pods;
[image]

Pod information;
[image]

Comment: `kubectl get events'  gives some useful info?

Comment: If you check the resource usage such as CPU, memory?

Comment: @NicolaBen, I attached relevant kubernetes events in description, please check.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT, I attached resource usage in the description, please check.

Comment: @Sudharshan I means you can check the node with command `kubectl describe node nodeName` if you just have one node. I see your other pods are in Pending state, maybe the resource is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the following [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cluster-large/):

> At v1.11, Kubernetes supports clusters with up to 5000 nodes. More
>   specifically, we support configurations that meet all of the following
>   criteria:
>
> ```
> No more than 5000 nodes
> No more than 150000 total pods
> No more than 300000 total containers
> No more than 100 pods per node
> ```

Your event log shows an `insufficient pods`

If your cluster doesn't have more than 10 working nodes, the scheduler cannot schedule less than 100 pods per node (and respect the fourth bound).

The same limitations occur with a kubernetes version before v.1.11.

Comment: You answered for insufficient pods event log, but my question is find the way of automatically created pods (kubernetes-cli-xxxxx). Because kubernetes-cli deployment not created by me.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be the case in your particular deployment, however something similar happened to me too and I'll post it in case someone Googles this question.

I had a failing job without a Delete policy, and this made it deploy itself 1000 times for some reason. Specifying a delete policy fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you please explain further on your fix.

Comment: @Sudharshan I don't think that your problem related to the `Delete` policy. Moreover, it is not applicable for `Deployments`. If you still can reproduce the issue, can you check post somewhere `kube-scheduler` logs and output of `kubectl describe node $your_node`?  There was some bugs related to that issue, but most of them should be fixed. BTW, which version of Minikube/Kubernetes you use?

Comment: @AntonKostenko
I couldn't see any log entries in kube-scheduler. And I'm using v1.6.6 version of Kubernetes.

Comment: @Sudharshan the reason of your issue should be visible in `kube-scheduler` logs, so try to find it. But, you have a pretty and already unsupported version of Kubernetes which can contain bugs fixed in modern versions, so I highly recommend you to update Kubernetes to 1.10 or 1.11, I think you have a big chance that update will fix your issue.